# Does UITextContentType provide suggestions for .textContentType(.creditCardNumber)?

Tags: swift, uitextcontenttype

In my code I can modify a `TextField` with `.textContentType(.streetAddressLine1)`.  Then when I tap this field I see a suggestion for what this string should be based on my contact card.

However when I try `.textContentType(.creditCardNumber)`. I see no suggestions. I'm not sure if I should have this info somewhere or, if at this time, iOS doesn't suggest prefills for credit card information.

The documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputtraits/1649656-textcontenttype)

> the system can in some cases automatically select an appropriate keyboard and improve keyboard corrections and proactive integration with other text input opportunities.

This to me suggests that some textContentTypes will provide suggestions and others won't.  Should `.textContentType(.creditCardNumber)` be providing suggestions or not?